# How to get a second join into hook_views_data?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to make the value of a string (name) found in `mymodule_names.name` available to **Views** by means of `hook_views_data()`.

To get the name, I need to first look up the `nid` of the node I want to view in a table named `mymodule`.  This tells me the *email-address* of user who authored the node.  Then I need to look up the email address in the table `mymodule_names`, by finding the row where the *same* email address is in the column `mymodule_names.email`. What I want returned is the user name attached to that email-address, which  the value of `mymodule_names.name` in the same row.

The code below is how far I have been able to get. This makes the value of `mymodule_names.email` available - but getting that is just an intermediary step.  I think I need a *second* join to get the user name. I am unable to figure out how to do do that.  How should I modify this code to get the data from the second table?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function mymodule_views_data() {
  $data = array();
  $data['mymodule']['table']['group'] = t('MyModule');
  $data['mymodule']['table']['base'] = array(
    // This is the identifier field for the view.
    'field' => 'nid',
    'title' => t('MyModule'),
    'help' => t('Table contains ...'),
    'weight' => -10,
  );

  // This table references the {node} table. The declaration below creates an
  // 'implicit' relationship to the node table, so that when 'node' is the base
  // table, the fields are automatically available.
  $data['mymodule']['table']['join'] = array(
    'node' => array(
      // Primary key
      'left_field' => 'nid',
      // Foreign key
      'field' => 'nid',
    ),
  );
  $data['mymodule']['nid'] = array(
  'title' => t('Title'),
    'help' => t('Help.'),
  );
  // Join with the email field.
  $data['mymodule']['email'] = array(
    'title' => t('Email'),
    'help' => t('Author email.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      // This is used by the table display plugin.
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
  );
  return $data;
}
```

(This is a non-standard setup where `node.uid` cannot be used to get the node author UID.)

I know how to get the name by inserting a subquery with `hook_views_query_alter()` (see: [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/28453/12076)). The question is about doing *without* using subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data['mymodule']['table']['join']['node'] = [
  //Second table for Join
  'left_table' => 'foo',
  'left_field' => 'nid',
  'field' => 'nid',
]
```

more info: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/8.6.x